# How to stop the spontaneous displacement of the desktop.ini files icons on the Windows 10 desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Hidden `desktop.ini` icons change its position itself when I refresh desktop or change the other icons location.

I want to see all hidden files so disabling `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` option does not fit me.

Here is the GIF of this issue:

[image: video]

Comment: That's some bizarre behavior that shouldn't be normal. Do you have any DPI settings adjusted or icon sizes or similar?

Comment: @Seth Nothing special - screen is `100% size`, two `album` monitors with 1920x1080 resolution and `Extend these displays` enabled.

Comment: Did you check whenever automatic arrangement of icons is enabled etc. on the right click menu on the desktop and/or did you try whenever one of those options resolves the problem?

Comment: What you have actually turned off that’s not really required is “Hide protected operating system files”. `desktop.ini` files are system hidden.

Comment: This is not too strange behavior. A desktop.ini file contains settings, and is updated as folder content changes. It moves because it is being updated. Although normally it would stay in place. You can try to delete the file manually so that it is recreated once you perform the action and see if it stays at the same place. I think it jumps because there are 2 desktop.ini files and only one is deleted. You will want to delete both of them before performing the action again.

Comment: The `desktop.ini` files contain folder customization. It does not change by dragging around icons. The behavior the OP is experiencing is _not_ normal.

Comment: That is odd behavior. Although dragging doesn't update the file, tone from my userprofile (as oposed to 'Public' ) ``did show a 'LastwriteTime' of '1/8/2020' --- more recent than anytime I might have played with it. If `Daniel B`'s suggestion of re-enabling `Hide protected...` doesn't suit you, try clearing the 'Hidden' attribute of the `desktop.ini` files and see if it behaves any better.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the position of the two desktop.ini files and it will stop.
It only happens if they are ordered in the reverse order they update in.

Comment: It is impossible to validate your proposal because this behavior is no longer occurs.